# In IIS7 Environment.UserName is different when the user has logged on

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, impersonation

I have a Asp.Net MVC application that runs on a shared host under IIS7. The application uses Forms Authentication with the default MembershipProvider. I have following code on one of my pages.

```
@Environment.UserDomainName - @Environment.UserName
```

When I visit the site as a anonymous user it shows: WSWB12 - IUSR_139
While if I'm logged in: WORKGROUP - WSWB12$

The problem is that only the IUSR account has write access to my folders. So when a user is logged in it cannot upload any files.

Can I do something about this? 
- I would very much prefer to stay with integrated mode.
- Doing impersonation would be ok to me. But it seems like my host has looked that section in machine.config
- Is there any settings my host could do on the virtual directory to make it always use IUSR?

Greatful for any help you can provide.

Comment: what error do you get when you try impersonation?

Comment: When I tried to add the impersonation section to the web.config I got an error saying that the section was locked in machine.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>With Forms Authentication, you should use</strike>

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

to access the Username...

You should check the Application Pool Identity. You can set that to a user of your choosing, that might have the correct privileges.

Comment: It's not the name of the logged in user that matters. It's the name of the Account which the appliction runs under that controls the IO access. So Environment.UserName is correct in this case.

Comment: Missed that one. It's a shared host and I do suspect they haven't set the account correctly. Maybe I should try to get them set the identity on either the application pool or on the website(connect as).

Comment: Can you just disable Windows Auth and set the identity of the Anonymous method to use the app pool identity? This is all web.config'rable

Comment: Accepted this answer because I'm pretty sure this is the solution. My host still claims they can't fix it though => new hosting